# Just a curious probability question of a line through a plane.

Tags: probability

This question was just a result of curiosity.

Let a line be drawn through a plane (consider a piece of paper).
A person randomly puts a dot on the plane. What is the probability that it will lie on the line?

As I thought, a line has no thickness and hence no area. So is it that there is no chance the person will put the dot on the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's simplify a little bit and consider lines in a square (so we avoid the unconfortable fact of dealing with the infinite area of the plane).

The probability that the dot will lie on the line is indeed $0$. This follows from the fact that, as you stated, the line has area equal to $0$.

Of course it's not technically *impossible* to put the dot in the line. But there are *uncountably many lines*, so the probability that we will choose a *specific* line is indeed zero.

When we deal with sample spaces that have uncountably many possible outcomes (as in this case) there will be non-impossible events that will have $0$ probabilities.